# Retrieving date from database in jaser

Tags: jasper-reports

I have date as `datetime` in mysql. But when I am retriving value in jasper I am getting null pointer.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS").format($F{birthDate})

```
<field name="birthDate" class="java.util.Date">
    <fieldDescription>
        <![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS").format($F{birthDate})]]>
    </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Please help me how do I get the correct date.

Comment: <field name="birthDate" class="java.util.Date">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS").format($F{birthDate})]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>

Comment: It looks like you want to combine a db field definition and a string representation thereof. Keep matters divided.

Comment: I have indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly and quoted error message so it looks more attractive.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) there are no `MI` pattern in «Date and Time Patterns». So, if you want to define the minutes then you must use `m` or `mm` patern. Also you must use `y` patern for year, `d` or `dd` patern to define the days in month. And use `s` or `ss` for seconds, because `S` is for milliseconds:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format($F{birthDate})
```